# How to query parse.com users through factory Service in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform, angularjs-service

Building an cross-platform hybrid app using Parse.com, AngularJS using the Ionic Framework. The user creation and querying works fine when using the simple parse.com code from the [docs](https://www.parse.com/docs/js_guide#users-querying).

However I have been trying to put the query into a AngularJS service, so that it can be accesses and I can do a `ng-repeat` to display the returned results in a list.

The code put in place so far is this:

View (search.html):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-75">
  <label class="item item-input">
    <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search.queryvalue">
  </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <button class="button button-calm" ng-click="searchnow()">Search</button>
  </div>
</div>

<ion-list>
  <ion-item class="item-avatar" type="item-text-wrap" ng-repeat="user in users">
      <img ng-src="{{userpic}}.png">
      <h2>{{user.id}}</h2>
      <p>{{user.get('location')}}</p>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Controller:

```
.controller('SearchCtrl', function($scope, $state, $rootScope, parseQueryFactory) {
  $scope.search = {};
  $scope.users = {};
  $scope.searchnow = function () {
    $scope.users = parseQueryFactory.searchUsers($scope.search.queryvalue);
  };
})
```

Services:

```
.factory('parseQueryFactory', function($http) {

  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  var people = {};

  return {
    searchUsers: function(searchVal){
      query.startsWith("username", searchVal);  // Search username
      query.limit(20);
      return query.find({
        success: function(people) {
          /*var objects = {};
          for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) { 
            var object = people[i];
            objects = objects + object;
          }
          console.log(people);
          return objects;*/
        },
        error: function(error) {
          return error;
        }
      });
  }
}
})
```

I have tried a few ways to make this work (using sources like the ionic forum, stackoverflow and Google in general), but I am new to angular and not sure how to go about doing this.

The only thing that works is by putting the following code in the controller (but then I cannot use `ng-repeat`):

```
$scope.searchnow = function () {
    var queryvalue = $scope.user.queryvalue;
    userquery.startsWith("username", queryvalue);  // Search username
    userquery.limit(20);
    userquery.find({
      success: function(people) {
        for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) { 
          var object = people[i];
          console.log("ID: " + object.id + ', username: ' + object.get('username'));
        }
      }, error: function(error) {
        console.log("error");
      }
    });
  };
```

Has anyone implemented such a service for parse.com?

I have looked around and tried implementations from various people, but nothing seems to work in a way that returns a service like response from which `ng-repeat` comands can be done.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this might help.

Services:

```
app.factory('Presentation', function($q) {


var Presentation = Parse.Object.extend(Parse.User, {
  // Instance methods
}, {
  // Class methods

  listByUser : function() {
    var defer = $q.defer();

    var query = new Parse.Query(this);


  query.startsWith("username", searchVal);  // Search username
  query.limit(20);
    query.find({
      success : function(aPresentations) {
        defer.resolve(aPresentations);
      },
      error : function(aError) {
        defer.reject(aError);
      }
    });

    return defer.promise;
  }
});

// Properties
Presentation.prototype.__defineGetter__("location", function() {
  return this.get("location");
});
  Presentation.prototype.__defineGetter__("pic", function() {
  var pic = this.get("pic");
        if (pic ==null){
            pic = 'img/default.png';
            return pic;
        }
        return pic.url();
});







return Presentation; });
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('userController', function( Presentation){
    user = this;

    Presentation.listByUser().then(function(aPresentations) {
    user.list = aPresentations;
}, function(aError) {
  // Something went wrong, handle the error
});
});
```

html:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col col-75">
<label class="item item-input">
<i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search.queryvalue">
</label>
</div>
<div class="col">
<button class="button button-calm" ng-     click="searchnow()">Search</button>
</div>
</div>

<ion-list>
<ion-item class="item-avatar" type="item-text-wrap" ng-repeat="user  in users">
<img ng-src="{{user.pic}}">
<h2>{{user.id}}</h2>
<p>{{user.location}}</p>
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

For further reading you can check out [5 Tips for using parse with angularjs](http://blog.slidebean.com/blog/2013/11/5/5-tips-for-using-parse-with-angularjs) by slidebean.